# Macros in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, macros

Just wondering, is there a way to use macros in Ruby that does an in-text substitution the way C would work?

For example:

```
define ARGS 1,2
sum(ARGS) # returns 3
```

EDIT:
More specifically my problem looks more like:

```
@button1 = FXButton.new(self, "Button 1",:opts => BUTTONPROPERTIES,:width => width, :height => height)
@button2 = FXButton.new(self, "Button 2",:opts => BUTTONPROPERTIES,:width => width, :height => height)
@button3 = FXButton.new(self, "Button 3",:opts => BUTTONPROPERTIES,:width => width, :height => height)
```

And ideally I'd want the code to look like:

```
@button1 = FXButton.new(self, "Button 1", ALLBUTTONPROPERTIES)
@button2 = FXButton.new(self, "Button 2", ALLBUTTONPROPERTIES)
@button3 = FXButton.new(self, "Button 3", ALLBUTTONPROPERTIES)
```

Notice how I have "width" and "height" variables that won't properly be passed to the initialization of the FXButton class if I just set them to some predetermined value.  Is there some kind of code substitution that would take care of this issue?

Comment: Can you describe the *problem* you are trying to solve w/ Ruby? Then perhaps we can better answer the question.

Comment: The actual "problem" is that I repeatedly type the same values for 3 arguments into a function and only changing one.  The problem is that some of the same arguments I'm typing are variables.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need a macro. Just define a variable or a constant.

```
A = [1, 2]
A.inject(:+) # => 3
```

---

**After the edit to your question**

You can do like this:

```
ALLBUTTONPROPERTIES = ->{{opts: => BUTTONPROPERTIES, width: width, height: height}}
```

and within a context where the constants and variables `BUTTONPROPERTIES`, `width`, `height` are assigned some value, do this:

```
@button1 = FXButton.new(self, "Button 1", ALLBUTTONPROPERTIES.call)
@button2 = FXButton.new(self, "Button 2", ALLBUTTONPROPERTIES.call)
@button3 = FXButton.new(self, "Button 3", ALLBUTTONPROPERTIES.call)
```

Comment: What does the call do?  I can't seem to find it anywhere.  Does that reassign the values of width and height?  What is the -> operator do?  Thanks again.

Comment: `->{...}` is called lambda. It creates a `Proc` object. It is not evaluated at its creation. `call` evaluates it within the given context.

Comment: Perfect! I had no idea that was the syntax for creating a lambda.  Thanks.  Best answer.

Answer (score 8):

There's probably another way around what you are trying to do. Preprocessors macros doesn't make sense because Ruby is not a compiled language, it is an interpreted language.

Particularly for your example there's a very clean way to do that:

```
args = [1, 2]
sum(*args) # equivalent to sum( 1, 2 )
```

Comment: So far this is the best answer I received.  Almost exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: I upvoted this answer.  Surprised there is a downvoter since it's a simple and direct answer.  I don't even have enough rep to downvote XD

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I believe the downvote would have come from the fact that your statement suggests that
(1) languages are either compiled or interpreted, and
(2) interpreted languages can't have a preprocessor.

Neither of these are true statements. Any language that can be interpreted can be compiled, and there's no reason a language that is usually interpreted can't make use of a preprocessor. Many functional languages, like Racket, Scheme, and other LISP dialects, utilize one to great effect; their capacity for powerful macros is part of what makes them so powerful themselves.

Comment: Nope, we preprocess typescript (adding await keyword inside generators) and ruby (thread-safe autoloading) at work

Answer (score 7):

There is no preprocess in ruby, a macros does not make sense. Simply use string constant or whatever other type of constant you need.

Answer (score 4):

Ruby way of solving your problem would probably be a bit different from your approach:

```
@buttons = ["Button 1", "Button 2", "Button 3"].map do |name|
  FXButton.new(self, name,
               :opts => BUTTONPROPERTIES,
               :width => width,
               :height => height)
end
```

In this example you don't have `@button1`, `@button2`, `@button3` variables. Instead `@buttons` is array containing all three.

Comment: I realize I didn't fully explain my problem.  Even if I do that for buttons 1-3, I may have to make another 3 buttons in a completely different class (not just instantiation) so I would have to rewrite all of that code still.